# how to get more than 24 hrs in a pxtimelist in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

how to get more than 24 hrs in a pxtimelist in acumatica.

In Acumatica we have currently PXTimeList to accept up to 24:00 hrs in a dropdown..

how can we increase the Time List in a dropdown. For Ex:50:00 or 45:30

Answer (score 0):

Use `PXDBTimeSpanLong` attribute instead of `PXTimeList` :

```
public abstract class timeSpent : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<timeSpent> { }

[PXDBTimeSpanLong(Format = TimeSpanFormatType.LongHoursMinutes)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Time Spent", Enabled = false)]
public virtual Int32? TimeSpent { get; set; }
```

Define the `MaxHours` property on the PXTimeSpan control:

```
<px:PXTimeSpan TimeMode="True" ID="edTimeSpent" runat="server" 
               DataField="TimeSpent" InputMask="hh:mm" MaxHours="99" />
```

This attribute uses a `MaskEdit` type control editor instead of a `ComboBox` type:
[image]